# How to check if a class level method is in superclass or in subclass in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have class tructure like this

```
@interface SuperClass: NSObject
+ (void) someName;
@end


@interface MyClass: SuperClass

@end
```

There is the case that i only want to call the `someName` if it is a class method of `MyClass` not `MyClass`'s superclass.  Since `[[MyClass class] respondsToSelector:@selector(someName)]` return YES if a class or its super response to the selector. How to tell that MyClass doesnt **contain** to`someName`?

In my application i want to print the string that contains chains of string return from a class method.

Take abve class structure as a example, i want to print something like:

```
somenameFromSuper.somenameFromClass.someNameFromeSubClass.
```

if a class doesnot implement `someName` method, i want to replace it by `notavailable, for ex:

```
somenameFromSuper.notavailable.someNameFromeSubClass.
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Wouldn't you just need to negate the test?

Comment: i updated the question, hope it make sense

Comment: Why don't you just check if `self` is `MyClass` i.e `if ([[self class] isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) ` thats assuming I also understood the question properly.

Comment: There is the case that i dont know the class name. like the example in my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_Bool class_implementsMethodForSelector( Class cls, SEL selector )
{

    unsigned methodsCount;
    Method* methods = class_copyMethodList(cls, &methodsCount);
    for (unsigned methodIndex=0; methodIndex<methodsCount; methodIndex++)
    {
        if (method_getName(methods[methodIndex]) == selector)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    free(methods);
    return  methodsIndex<methodsCount;
}

…

Class classToTest = …;
classToTest = object_getClass(classToTest); // For checking class methods
if (class_implementsMethodForSelector(classToTest, @selector(someName))
{
    …
}
else
{
    …
}
```

Typed in Safari.

Edit: Made a function of it. Still typed in Safari.

Comment: how about instance methods? Does it apply for instance methods?

Comment: simply omit `classToTest = object_getClass(classToTest);`. To make a long story short: You ask the class for the instance methods. To get the class methods as in the sample, you ask the "class' class" (metaclass). That's was the statement does.

Comment: You have a memory leak.  Don't forget to call free(methods);

Comment: Thx, this was the reason, why I did not use return …