# Objective-C class @implementation block - How to reference name/class inside

Tags: objective-c

I would like know name of the implementation block.  The compiler provides

```
__FILE__
```

to give you the compile time file name, I have not been able to find any method to get the current implementation block name.  Something like this would work:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    +(NSString*)implementationBlockName {
        return __IMPL_BLOCK_NAME__;
    }
}
```

But I'm looking for any way to get this information.  Note: I am not looking for the runtime type of an object or type of class that happens to be the 'self' when these are called.

As an added example, a place where this would be very useful is in the +(void)initialize method.  Each subclass will call all the +(void)initialize methods in its chain.  Often, you would want the initialization to run only once, so the code looks like this:

```
+(void)initialize {
    if(self == [MyImplementationBlockClass class]) {
        // Do implementation
    }
}
```

This is obviously error prone, you can easily put the wrong class name in there and nothing will warn you.  If there was a way to reference the @implementation type, it would save errors:

```
if(self == __MAGIC_IMPL_CLASS__) {...}
```

Comment: Have you tried `[self class]` ?

Comment: [self class] returns the runtime type, I need the type of implementation block.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "obviously error prone" is something that never goes wrong. And it is really hard to find a use case for your question, if OOP programming paradigms are respected. However:

If the method is not overridden in subclasses – *which is a more error prone assumption by far* – you can check for the implementation of the method starting at `[self class]` running the inheritance upwards.

An easy way to check the implementation of a method on a specific class is posted here:
[How to check if a class level method is in superclass or in subclass in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563322/how-to-check-if-a-class-level-method-is-in-superclass-or-in-subclass-in-objectiv/25564428#25564428)

Comment: Thanks - Still doesn't quite get me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not? It does what you described in your Q.

Comment: The "not overridden" part is the hypothetical.  What I'm actually looking for is a developer-simple way to annotate classes and this is the one part that I don't have an elegant solution for (cleanly knowing what implementation block something is in).

Comment: The requirements mentioned by you in the Q are hypothetical without mentioning that this requirement is not valid, but a wy of hypothetical, optional, whatever? Man …

Comment: The requirement was for them to not be overridden because then the code displayed would not run.  I'll edit the question to ask only what I need.

Comment: Good idea to edit the Q and to say what you want. When you have done this, you can reread my answer, which is still valid, if `-implementationClassName` *is* overridden.

Answer (score -2):

Best way I've been able to come up with:

```
#define IMPL_CLASS MyClassName

@implementation IMPL_CLASS {
    // use IMPL_CLASS everywhere you want the implementation block
}
```

Better answers very much welcome.

Comment: And what is the advantage in comparison to `NSStringFromClass([FooClass class]);`?

Comment: Not much honestly.  It prevents having to specify the name in multiple places, and might be easier to nest in other macros.

Comment: And if you put it in a method, you have to use it in multiple places?